Align cells in the centre (vertically and horizontally) in longtblr
Consider the MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs} % new tables
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {List of acronyms and their first appearance.},
    label = {listofacronyms},
    ]{
        colspec = {@{}Q[m,0.15\textwidth]@{} Q[c,0.5\textwidth]@{} Q[m,0.2\textwidth] @{}Q[m,0.15\textwidth]@{}},
        %hlines,
        %row{even} = {gray9},
        %row{1} = {olive9},
    } 
\toprule
  ABD & A very long description here that would sometimes span 2 lines & Short & Also Short \\
  QCD & Another, perhaps even longer description here that would sometimes span 2 lines & Short & Also Short \\
  LMB & Maybe a short one & Short & Stil \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}

How can I make the entries centered both horizontally and vertically? When I run this I get them centered horizontally but not vertically when the second row takes up multiple lines.

The solution was m,c:
    colspec = {@{}Q[m,c,0.15\textwidth]@{} Q[m,c,0.5\textwidth]@{} Q[m,c,0.2\textwidth] @{}Q[m,c,0.15\textwidth]@{}},

